# Remove tooltip from kartik/date/datepicker

Tags: datepicker, yii2, tooltip

I use kartik DatePicker in my activeform.

```
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
```

My activeform field:

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'transferred_date')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
                        'value' => date('d-M-Y', strtotime('+2 days')),
                        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select date ...'],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                            'todayHighlight' => true
                        ]
    ])->label('Transferred Date');
?>
```

When I hover the mouse on calendar icon, it shows a tool tip like this.
[image]

I have to remove the tooltip. How can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading the [doc](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker) you can read this in the settings:

> **pickerButton**: mixed the calendar picker button configuration - applicable only when type is set to **DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_PREPEND** or **DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND**. This can be one of the following types:
>   string, if this is a string, it will be displayed as is (and will not be HTML encoded).
>   boolean, if this is set to false, it will not be displayed.
>   array, this is the default behavior. If passed as an array, it will be considered as HTML attributes for the picker button addon. The following special keys are recognized:
>   icon, string the bootstrap glyphicon name/suffix. Defaults to 'calendar'.
>   **title, string|boolean the title to be displayed on hover. Defaults to 'Select date & time'. If this is set to false, it will not be displayed**.

So i can say without testing that it should be something like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'transferred_date')
         ->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
                    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_PREPEND,
                    'pickerButton' => ['title' => false],
                    'value' => date('d-M-Y', strtotime('+2 days')),
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select date ...'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                        'todayHighlight' => true
                    ]
          ])->label('Transferred Date');
?>
```

So you missed this in the config:

```
'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_PREPEND,
'pickerButton' => ['title' => false],
```